# mongoose aggregate with conditional parameters

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have this working aggregation code for mongoose

```
    const AccountProduct = await AccountProductModel.aggregate([
            {
                $match: { userID: userID }
            },
            {
                $addFields: {
                    taggedProducts: {
                        $filter: {
                            input: "$taggedProducts",
                            cond: {
                                 $and: {
                                    $eq: [ "$$this.isChecked", true ],
                                    $eq: [ "$$this.walletID", walletID]
                                 }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ])
```

it does return the required data but I want to have a condition if walletID is not supplied then condition should look like this

```
                        cond: {
                             $and: {
                                $eq: [ "$$this.isChecked", true ]
                             }
                        }
```

how do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the condition into a variable before the query.

```
let myCond = [{$eq: [ "$$this.isChecked", true ]}];

if (walletID) myCond.push({$eq: [ "$$this.walletID", walletID]});
```

Then

```
cond: {$and: myCond}
```